# How to match two consecutive identical words except for the case of the initial characters?

Tags: regular-expressions, words, query-replace-regexp

I'm looking for a solution to match two consecutive identical words except for the case of the initial characters with `query-replace-regexp`:

```
The the
the The
```

I can't figure out how to match these typos with a regular expression at once because I don't know how to use `downcase` or `capitalize` in the searching part as I usually do in the replacement part (e.g. with `lambda`). I mean something like this:

```
;; THIS CODE IS WRONG!!!
(query-replace-regexp (concat "\\(\\(\\<[A-Z][[:alpha:]]+\\>\\)\\)\\([~\s\n]+\\)"
                              `((lambda (data count))
                                (downcase (match-string 1))))
                      nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

Of course I know this is wrong and so I tried this code for the first kind of typo:

```
;; "The the" case
(let (cap-word space typo)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "\\(\\([A-Z]\\)\\([[:alpha:]]+\\)\\)\\([ ~\n]+\\)" nil t)
    (save-excursion
      (setq cap-word (match-string 1)
            space (match-string 2)
            typo (concat cap-word
                         space
                         (downcase cap-word))

            (when (looking-at typo)

              ;; do things

              ))))
```

It works, but it's slow and, overall, does not match my typos at once. Is there a way to do that?

**Review**

I said the code above works, but it's not true. Sorry: I posted the wrong version of the code, so I'm putting the right one below for completeness:

```
;; "The the" case
(let ((case-fold-search nil)
      cap-word space down-word typo)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "\\<\\([A-Z]\\)\\([[:alpha:]]+\\)\\>\\([ ~\n]+\\)" nil t)
      (save-excursion
        (setq cap-word (concat (match-string 1)
                               (match-string 2))
              space (match-string 3)
              down-word (downcase cap-word)
              typo (concat cap-word
                           space
                           down-word))

        (when (looking-at down-word)

          ;; do things

          )))))
```

Comment: For clarity, is it *actually* an important requirement that the two consecutive identical words have different first-letter case?  I'm asking because the majority of instances of repeated words *without* case changes are going to be mistakes as well, and so I'd be more inclined to have a query-replace process over *all* such potential errors.

Comment: What @phils asked. Would a case-insensitive match not be sufficient?

Comment: @phils Yes, it is: I already have a script that deals with two consecutive identical words, but recently I came across the case "The the" that was pointed out to me by the authors (I'm a professional LaTeX typesetter).

Comment: @Drew Unfortunately not: The code I posted above is just part of a very long function that takes care of various things and I need to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous bugs in that code, but perhaps something like this is what you want?

```el
(let ((case-fold-search nil)
      (word "\\b\\([[:word:]]\\)\\([[:word:]]*\\)\\b[[:space:]]*")
      initial suffix typo)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward word nil t)
      (setq initial (match-string 1)
            suffix (match-string 2)
            typo (concat (if (string-match-p "[[:upper:]]" initial)
                             (downcase initial)
                           (upcase initial))
                         suffix "\\b"))
      (when (looking-at typo)
        (message "%s" (match-string 0))))))
```

---

Edit: On review, I'd actually go with this approach:

```el
(let ((case-fold-search t)
      (regexp "\\b\\([[:word:]]+\\)[[:space:]]+\\(\\1\\)\\b"))
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward regexp nil t)
      (unless (string= (match-string 1) (match-string 2))
        (message "%s" (match-string 0))))))
```

This is comparing the case of the whole word, not just the first letter, but I assumed that was fine.

You can use `(aref STRING 0)` to obtain the first character if need be (and compare those with `eql` rather than `string=`).  The initial match is case-insensitive though, so you'd potentially want to compare the remainder of each word as well.  I'm guessing you don't need to do any of that, though.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please explain to me what bugs are you talking about?

Comment: You weren't disabling `case-fold-search` and so you were very likely matching case-insensitively.  Your group numbers and associated bindings are wrong (your group 1 is the word, group 2 is the first letter, not `space`) which then messes up your `typo` value.  And as `re-search-forward` leaves point at the end of the match, you're only going to be `(looking-at typo)` if the text was "The The the" (assuming `typo` was as you had intended).

Comment: Thank you very much! You are definitely right! I posted the wrong version of the code: I had changed the regular expression to search for `The ` and didn't update the groups below. As for `case-fold-search`, as this code is part of a very long function, where `case-fold-search` is active, I haven't repeated it in my code above, but I should have specified it. Sorry.